# Image Circulation in android

Tags: android, image, slider

I have created a app to find the hotels, I am using a slider to show all images related to the hotel's. But I want to get the first image after the last slide in circular fashion.

Get idea through below Picture, Because I want to achieve it in same way.

[image] Sliding [image] Sliding[image]Sliding[image]Sliding[image]

All image must be in circular fashion with no end point for image in gallery while sliding.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the below library called `InfiniteScrollView`.

I think this will do exactly what you are looking for.

https://github.com/satansly/InfiniteScrollView

Comment: Thnks Anuj,I am trying to take some idea from there.